# Conexión php odbc con acentos y caracteres especiales

Tags: php, json, odbc

estoy construyendo un webservice con PHP que se conecta a una base de datos con odbc y lee sus registros. Esto me lo hace bien, pero cuando alguno de los campos de la base de datos tiene acentos o ñ o caracteres especiales, el webservice no me devuelve nada (ni error), simplemente no me muestra nada.

Así tengo mi webservice:

```
<?php
    define('CHARSET','UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    $usuario='';

    $pass='';

    $dsn='Tr3';

    $conexion = odbc_connect($dsn,$usuario,$pass);


   $sql="select total, name, domin from F_VENTA where Ve_FirmaCamion=true";


    $rs = odbc_exec($conexion, $sql);
    if (!$rs) {
        exit("Error al conectar la base de datos");
    }
    $datos = array();
    $i = 1;

    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {

        $datos[] = $row;
        $i++; 
    }


    odbc_close($conexion);

    $json = json_encode($datos);

    echo $json;

?>
```

En principio, esto funciona bien. Pero si el campo "name" tiene acentos, no me devuelve nada. Si utiliza la expresión print_r($datos), sí me vienen los datos bien (aunque los caracteres extraños me salen con un rombo negro), pero bueno, al menos muestra algo.

He intentado usar las funciones replace, convert, cast... pero todas me devuelven este error:

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Paradox]
>   La funci�n 'replace' no est� definida en la expresi�n., SQL state
>   37000

¿Alguna pista de dónde está mi error?

Answer (score 1):

Asegurate que los campos de la base de datos están configurados como utf8, utf8_general_ci porque tiene pinta de que el error va por ahí.

También te recomiendo utilizar la función utf8_encode(campo) para que desaparezcan los caracteres extraños.

Answer (score 1):

Aporto mi solución al problema por si le pasara a alguien más.

Lo he conseguido solucionar si antes de codificar los datos a json, les paso el método
`mb_convert_encoding()` a los datos que nos llegan desde la base de datos mientras los recorre. Así los voy codificando en el ciclo while:

```
 while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {

            $datos[] = mb_convert_encoding($row, "UTF-8", "iso-8859-1");

            $i++;
}
```

Saludos a la comunidad!

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que es la codificación, en mi caso suelo usar este parametro en el conector a la BD (uso adodb)

**$db->EXECUTE("set names 'utf8'");**